# UnityWebRequest Memory Leak

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a simple game that spawns bugs that move from one side of the screen to the other. They vary in type, size, speed and order. If the player taps the bug on the screen, it explodes and disappears (is destroyed). When it reaches the other side of the screen, it also disappears (is destroyed). I wanted to add statistics to know which bugs were being tapped based on their properties. I added a UnityWebRequest but now I'm getting a memory leak error. I've read through many different examples and questions/answers, but can't figure it out. The game works fine without the statistics.

I have a script attached to each prefab bug called "TapToKill":

```
   void OnMouseUp() {
        bug = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Bug>();
        if (bug.isDead) return;

        bug.isDead = true;
        saveSpeed = bug.speed;
        bug.speed = 0f;
        GameObject bomb = Instantiate(explosion, bug.transform.position, bug.transform.rotation);
        Destroy(bomb, 0.5f);
        SoundManager.Instance.PlaySound(killedSound);
        BugsMain.score += 10;
        --BugsMain.count;
        BugsMain.bugIsActive[bug.bip] = false;
        // Used to destroy the gameobject here, but now hide it and post stats
        bug.rend.enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(PostRequest());
    }
```

Here's my post:

```
IEnumerator PostRequest() {
    const string url = "http://catstats.local/catstats.php";
    const string game = "bugs";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("game", game);
    form.AddField("type", bug.bugType);
    form.AddField("scale", bug.scale.ToString());
    form.AddField("speed", saveSpeed.ToString());
    form.AddField("spawnNumber", bug.spawnNumber.ToString());
    form.AddField("dirX", bug.dirX.ToString());
    form.AddField("x", bug.x.ToString());
    form.AddField("y", bug.y.ToString());
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
        Debug.Log("Data Sent: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
        EndItAll();
    } else { 
        Debug.Log("Error sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
```

And finally:

```
private void EndItAll() {
    StopCoroutine(PostRequest());
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

The actual error is:

```
 Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Allocated from:
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1:.ctor(Byte[], Allocator)
UnityEngine.Networking.UploadHandlerRaw:.ctor(Byte[])
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest:SetupPost(UnityWebRequest, WWWForm)
```

Any thoughts on how I can get rid of the memory leak? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Dispose.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) `UnityWebRequest.Post` implements [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0) and must be disposed after it has been used. You can do this automatically with a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) block:

```
using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form))
{
    ...
}
```

This will automatically dispose of the resources that the post uses, and will avoid the memory leak problem.